# Can you help me identify this integrated circuit component marked FH4 2103?

Tags: mosfet, digital-logic, integrated-circuit, mosfet-driver

I ordered (among many other components) some half-bridge drivers about 2 months ago, verified only the packet labels on the items in the order, and put them away for later use.

Fast-forward to today when I depleted my other stock and opened up the new packet to use the components.  While the packet label was correct, the contents were not.
[image]
The first image is the desired component (SO-8 package) outside the envelope and the components I received (maybe 10-pin SSOP package?), still in the cut-tape carrier, on the inside of the envelope.

Since it is past the return window for the order I can't use the distributor's (Thief River Falls, MN, USA) system for correcting the order.
[image]

The second image is a close-up of the component in question.  Maybe someone can recognize the logo or part number?

It's mostly a curiosity at this point, but thanks in advance to anyone who can identify this component.

Comment: I would lean on them and explain that they have made a shipping fault. I don't see how you can be held responsible for their errors. If necessary, and maybe as a last resort, you can mention that if you don't get a satisfactory result then this post (this one here that you wrote) will be easily seen by other potential customers and, they might just change their mind. I'll also point out that the word "Thief" appears in their name. Just saying.

Comment: The only distributor that I know of in Thief River Falls, MN is Digi-Key.

Comment: @Andy, @jwh20; I was being deliberately oblique about the distributor.  And it's more of a curiosity to find out what function the shipped part really performs.   The fault is mine for not doing a more thorough incoming inspection and the price of my parts does not really warrant placing an order just for that part, nor the time spent hassling the distributor.  I've used them for 35+ years and this is the first time I've ever experienced this particular problem.

Comment: I think you have decent grounds for making a return. The actual part you received I can't help you with.

Comment: It might have been an ordering error, picking or the wrong item was put into the wrong box. DK has a pretty robust process but it helps everyone if they are informed when they make a mistake. Things don’t magically fix themselves. Even if they don’t take the return, finding the root cause is useful. Most of the time it is a bit of dyslexia - swap a number here or there.

Comment: @Kartman  I'm sure it was a picking error when someone was pre-packaging 10-lots of chips for faster order fulfillment later.  And I've taken to heart your suggestion that pointing out the error might still benefit them and probably others down the road.  And, like many components, the distributor is currently out of stock on this part, so maybe they want them back.

Comment: Final resolution after talking with Digi-Key:  They don't want the part back because of ISO certification rules (probably hard to re-certify parts out of their control and probably an involved process to match the part in hand with their warehouse stock)  But they are issuing me a credit memo for the incorrect line item on that order.  When you actually reach a person they are courteous and helpful.  Refreshing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Littlefuse SP4044 Series TVS diode array.](https://www.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/datasheets/tvs_diode_arrays/littelfuse_tvs_diode_array_sp4044_datasheet.pdf.pdf)

Last page of datasheet details the "FH4" marking.

Comment: Well done!  Thanks very much for your help.  I see that the distributor is actually out of stock on that part so they might be willing to still make the trade.  It will just take a little more persistence on my part.